# To add Delete option in Webgrid with Edit option

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I have WebGrid and in that grid I have added Edit option. But i also want to add Delete option in same grid column. Below is my code to add Edit option.

```
grid.Column(header: "Actions",format: 
@<form method="get" action="/SuperAdmin/CustomerDetails/@item.FkCompanyId">
<input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Edit" class="ActionEdit" />
</form>)
```

Edit option will redirect to action `"/SuperAdmin/CustomerDetails/@item.FkCompanyId"` which is working. And Delete option should redirect to `"/SuperAdmin/DeleteManageCustomers/@item.Id"`.
Any idea how to do?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can add a new column for delete. Similar to edit column

```
grid.Column(header: "Edit",format: 
@<form method="get" action="/SuperAdmin/CustomerDetails/@item.FkCompanyId">
<input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Edit" class="ActionEdit" />
</form>),
grid.Column(header: "Delete",format: 
@<form method="get" action="/SuperAdmin/DeleteManageCustomers/@item.Id">
<input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Delete" class="ActionEdit" />
</form>),
```